# How do I install coala on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: coala

I've heard about this coala linting/static analysis tool,
and I wanted to give it a try.

So I ran `sudo apt-get install coala`
but that gave me the wrong program,
that `coala` is some kind of compiler, not what I wanted at all.

What is the correct way to install coala

Comment: Did you try reading the [Setup Details](https://coala.io/#details) page? (Which suggests a different command line, so I'm guessing the answer is either "no", or you did and you got some kind of error, but have chosen for some reason not to tell us about)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I actually did, this is kinda a staged question.
I am checking that the [coala gitter channel](https://gitter.im/coala/coala) SO integration is working. See https://github.com/coala/engagement/issues/46.
While also documenting a potentially common mistake on stackoverflow where it could be found easily via google.

Feel free to extend your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coala (the linter) is currently not packaged for ubuntu. You need to uninstall the `coala` package you have via `apt`, then you can install coala with all it's analysis using `pip install coala-bears`.

The full installation instructions are on https://coala.io/install including some hints about python virtualenvs.

I also filed [an issue](https://github.com/coala/documentation/issues/392) about your problem so it gets mentioned in our installation guide.

Answer (score 1):

"Ubuntu Users - Do not use apt-get install coala for installing coala as that is different software." - see http://coala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Users/Install.html

Use: 
$ pip3 install coala 
$ pip3 install coala-bears